# Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Ves\PageBuilder\Model\Config\Source\ElementList does not exist

Tags: magento2.3, exception, third-party-module

Magento 2.3.7, PHP 7.4.30

I installed the VES Page Builder extension (downloaded file from land of coder) manually, according to their readme:

Upload module files in the module packages in to folder: app/code/Ves/All, app/code/Ves/Setup, app/code/Ves/BaseWidget, app/code/Ves/PageBuilder

Then run commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

It installed fine, but didn't work.

I wanted to get rid of the extension, deleted all files and performed:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now when I want to edit an existing product or create a new product, I get an exception:

1 exception(s):

```
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Ves\PageBuilder\Model\Config\Source\ElementList does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Ves\PageBuilder\Model\Config\Source\ElementList does not exist
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
#5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:642]
#6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1181]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:697]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->setupAttributeMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:408]
#9 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getContainerChildren() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:381]
#10 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->addContainerChildren() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:356]
#11 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getAttributesMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:316]
#12 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->modifyMeta() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/ProductDataProvider.php:73]
#13 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider->getMeta() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:318]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadata() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:218]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:352]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:66]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:259]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:884]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#27 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction.php:72]
#28 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:248]
#30 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#31 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#32 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#33 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#34 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#35 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/NewAction/Interceptor.php:26]
#36 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\NewAction\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
```

What I tried:

I deleted:

www/m2/var/cache

www/m2/var/page-cache

www/m2/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static

I also tried:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php -d memory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks...

Comment: Found it - there was an orphaned entry in the database: in table eav_attribute was an attribute with the source_model entry 'Ves\PageBuilder\Model\Config\Source\ElementList'. I deleted that attribute from the table and life is good again... :)

Answer (score 0):

IN database search "ElementList" this keyword or whole path, and delete entry of this path from database.